# Execute .sql script using python3

Tags: sql, python-3.x, db2

I have a .sql file with a set of statements. I have been using shell execution in my python script using `db2 +v -txf` to execute the .sql script against my IBM DB2 instance. Is there any better way to execute script and get return codes without executing in shell. I am using python3.6.

Comment: What criteria do you use to decide "better" ?  You can get return codes from the db2 clp when executing a file containing both SQL and commands, and these return codes are documented in the Db2 knowledge Centre.    When executing via python, you cannot mix commands and SQL (you can only give SQL, and any command has to be executed via ADMIN_CMD() stored procedure if your Db2-server platform supports that (only Db2-LUW supports it).

Comment: I was looking for an alternate approach to execute the sql script. I don't want to execute shell commands.

Comment: What is your motivation for wanting to avoid executing shell-commands?

Comment: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb, though you'll need to parse your script into individual statements (which should be trivial with Python).